How should I run my mongodb migrations in a Dockerized app?
I am new to Docker and was wondering how I should run my migrations. I'm using the following Dockerfile for my Node js backend
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.13

RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3001 

RUN npm run db:up
CMD ["npm", "start"]

npm run db:up just runs my migrations using migrate-mongo up
I also have a frontend and db that use a compose.yml file to run all my containers. Below is my compose.yml file.
services:
  web:
    depends_on:
      - api
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    # environment:
    #   - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
    develop:
      watch:
        - path: ./frontend/package.json
          action: rebuild
        - path: ./frontend/package-lock.json
          action: rebuild
        - path: ./frontend
          target: /app
          action: sync
  api:
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: true
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    environment:
      DB_URL: mongodb://db/vidly
    develop:
      watch:
        - path: ./backend/package.json
          action: rebuild
        - path: ./backend/package-lock.json
          action: rebuild
        - path: ./backend
          target: /app
          action: sync
    command: ./docker-entrypoint.sh
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - vidly:/data/db
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongosh mongo:27017/test --quiet 1
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
volumes:
  vidly:

I'm getting the error
 => ERROR [api 7/7] RUN npm run db:up                                                                    33.0s
------
 > [api 7/7] RUN npm run db:up:
0.889
0.889 > vidly-backend@1.0.0 db:up /app
0.889 > migrate-mongo up
0.889
32.90 ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
32.90     at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/migrate-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:292:38)
32.90     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
32.90     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
32.94 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
32.94 npm ERR! errno 1
32.95 npm ERR! vidly-backend@1.0.0 db:up: `migrate-mongo up`
32.95 npm ERR! Exit status 1
32.95 npm ERR!
32.95 npm ERR! Failed at the vidly-backend@1.0.0 db:up script.
32.95 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
32.96
32.96 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
32.96 npm ERR!     /home/app/.npm/_logs/2024-06-17T16_51_27_332Z-debug.log
------

when I try to run docker-compose up.
This error means that mongod isn't running yet and therefore the migration fails. At least I think so. I thought by setting depends_on=db on my compose.yml file, my backend service would only run once mongod is executed, but that doesn't seem to be the case.
My question is how would I ensure my migrations get run after mongod is executed?
EDIT

My mongo db connection string is mongodb://localhost:27017 for my host machine. The container uses  DB_URL: mongodb://db/vidly
I have updated my code to use the healthcheck option, however I am still getting the same error.


can you share connection string in your code application ?

Just edited. Thanks for the reply.

From https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/:

On startup, Compose does not wait until a container is "ready", only until it's running. This can cause issues if, for example, you have a relational database system that needs to start its own services before being able to handle incoming connections.
The solution for detecting the ready state of a service is to use the condition attribute with one of the following options:

service_started
service_healthy. This specifies that a dependency is expected to be “healthy”, which is defined with healthcheck, before starting a dependent service.
service_completed_successfully. This specifies that a dependency is expected to run to successful completion before starting a dependent service.


Mongodb is not relational, yet still a database and does need some time to spin up and start listening on the port after the container started.
As the documentation suggests you need to add the healthcheck and condition to your compose.yml. The simplest example could be something like that:
  api:
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: true
   .....skipped the rest for brevity ....

  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - vidly:/data/db
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongosh mongo:27017/test --quiet 1
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10

You can run any command and adjust timeout/interval as well as number of attempts to tailor it to your environment. Please be creative. For inspiration, the test option could be:
test: ["CMD","mongosh", "--eval", "db.adminCommand('ping')"]

to connect to localhost and benefit from localhost exception, etc. Play with it to find out what works the best for you.
